# php foreach to print multidimensional array into table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

So, I am sending a query based on a POST input that takes in numerous options, and want to print out one table PER selected option.  I implode the array and it is correctly displaying the data, however it's all lumped up into one table where I need it separated.  This is an example of my array now:

```
Array
(
[Selected Option 1] => Array
    (
        [Item 1] => Array
            (
                [Item 1 Data 1] => etc
                [Item 1 Data 2] => etc
                [Item 1 Data 3] => etc
            )

    )
```

And basically I need the table to be like Table 1: Selected Option 1 displaying all items and their data, followed by Table 2: Selected Option 2, and so on.

How is something like this done? When I do the foreach loop, it successfully prints out the header to each table (Selected Option 1, etc) but Im not sure how to filter it so only the correct data is printed instead of the ENTIRE array.

Thanks!

So far, this is what my foreach looks like

```
    foreach ($selected_opt as $port=> $item) { 
                foreach ($item as $itemx => $data){

                $var1= $data['1'];
                $var2= $data['2'];

                $var3= $data['3'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach inside foreach

let say your array is = $data

```
<?php


    foreach ($data as $selectedOption => $items) {
         echo $selectedOption . "<br>";
         foreach ($items as $itemName => $itemData) {
            echo $itemName . "<br>";
            foreach ($itemData as $item) {
                echo $item . "<br>";
            }
         }
    }

?>
```

If you want to filter

```
echo $data["Selected Option 1"]["Item 1"]
```